# Traverse Tree and finding all possible path to target

Tags: python, binary-tree, tree-traversal

Original Question:
Given the root of a binary tree and an integer targetSum, return *the number of paths where the sum of the values along the path equals* targetSum. The path does not need to start or end at the root or a leaf, but it must go downwards (i.e., traveling only from parent nodes to child nodes).

I have posted my implementation below

Fails on test case: [1,null,2,null,3,null,4,null,5] , tagetSum = 3
it return 3 instead of 2

[image]

After some debugging I found out that node with value 3 is recorded twice, does anyone know why?

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right


class Solution:
    def pathSum(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], targetSum: int) -> int:

        self.res = 0

        def dfs(node, sum):
            if not node:
                return
            
            sum += node.val

            if sum == targetSum:
                self.res += 1
            
            dfs(node.left, 0)
            dfs(node.right, 0)

            dfs(node.left, sum)
            dfs(node.right, sum)

        dfs(root, 0)
        return self.res
```

Asked chatGPT and got the right solution...

```
class Solution:
    def pathSum(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], targetSum: int) -> int:

        self.res = 0

        def dfs(node, sum):
            if not node:
                return

            sum += node.val

            if sum == targetSum:
                self.res += 1

            dfs(node.left, sum)
            dfs(node.right, sum)

        def traverse(node):
            if not node:
                return

            dfs(node, 0)
            traverse(node.left)
            traverse(node.right)

        traverse(root)
        return self.res
```

Can someone explain the difference between the 2 implementaiton, I feel like they are doing the same thing.

Comment: Side note: I would add `if sum < targetSum:` above the bottom two `dfs()` calls to prevent unnecessary traversal.

Comment: I did that because node.val could be negative.

Comment: In that case it makes sense. Could you illustrate the tree in a better way other than a list? Is it a tree with only right nodes? Right now it's hard to tell exactly.

Comment: Can you add the code for the TreeNode class if it's possible?

Comment: Before each recursive call to `dfs`, try adding a print statement that tells you something like `Node2 calling dfs(Node3, 0)`. I think you're going to find that a dfs with initial value 0 is initiated twice on the node with value 3 - that's why you find the duplication in the result.

Comment: That's because the initial dfs on Node1 calls `dfs(Node2, 0)` and `dfs(Node2, 1)` - then **both** of those instantiations of the function make their own call `dfs(Node3, 0)`.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?  I copied your code and got a result of 1, so I'm not able to reproduce your original issue.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, in your version two recursive calls are made on `node.left`. They have different sums (well, if `sum` is not 0!), but then **both** of those executions of `dfs` will have their own recursive call of `dfs(node.left, 0)` which is done to start new paths at that node. But this means `dfs` is called multiple times with the same arguments without any reason for a double count.

This does not happen in the correct solution. There the call with 0 is only made in `traverse`. Those calls determine the starting node of the paths that will be inspected. `dfs` takes care of trying all possible paths from the same starting node. In your code the two concepts are mixed and lead to duplicates.

I add here an alternative implementation that keeps track of the root-to-node sums in a list and then checks if the current sum (from the root) differs with exactly `targetSum` from a previous sum on the path.

```
class Solution:
    def pathSum(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], targetSum: int) -> int:
        def dfs(node, total, sums):
            if not node:
                return 0
            total += node.val
            count = sum((total - start == targetSum) for start in sums)
            sums.append(total)
            count += dfs(node.left, total, sums) + dfs(node.right, total, sums)
            sums.pop()
            return count

        return dfs(root, 0, [0])
```